# find rank in mysql after multiple join

Tags: php, mysql, join

I am trying to find `rank` by the total points that a users earn. I do have this query but not getting idea on how to proceed.

```
SELECT
wp_grank.ID ,
wp_grank.competitor_ID ,
wp_grank.tournament_ID ,
wp_grank.academy_ID ,
wp_grank.division_ID,
wp_competitor.first_name,
wp_competitor.last_name,
wp_competitor.global_ID,
wp_divisions.gender,
IF(wp_divisions.age_level IN ('Tiny Kids','Kids','Pre Teen','Teen'),CONCAT('(',wp_divisions.gender,')'),'') as filterGender,
wp_tournaments.`name` as tournament_name,
wp_divisions.name as dname,
CONCAT_WS(' >> ', wp_divisions.division_type, wp_divisions.experience_level, wp_divisions.age_level, wp_divisions.weight_class, wp_divisions.gender) as division,
wp_academies.`name` as academy ,
SUM(wp_grank.points) as totalPoints
FROM
`wp_grank`
LEFT JOIN
wp_competitor
ON
wp_grank.competitor_ID = wp_competitor.ID
LEFT JOIN
wp_tournaments
ON
wp_grank.tournament_ID = wp_tournaments.ID
LEFT JOIN
wp_academies
ON
wp_grank.academy_ID = wp_academies.ID
LEFT JOIN
wp_divisions
ON
wp_grank.division_ID = wp_divisions.ID
WHERE
wp_divisions.ID IN (2) AND
YEAR(wp_tournaments.tournament_date)=2015
Group BY
wp_competitor.ID
ORDER BY
SUM(wp_grank.points) DESC ,wp_competitor.`last_name` ASC
```

Comment: Can u post a sample output of your current code? and also your exected output.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you just want to add a ranking column to the query.  If so:

```
set @rank = 0

select (@rank := @rank + 1) as rank, 
       . . .
```

Sometimes, variables don't work well with `group by`, so you need a subquery:

```
select (@rank := @rank + 1) as rank, q.*
from (<your query here>) q cross join
     (select @rank := 0) params;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one:

```
SET
    @prev = 0,
    @curr = 0,
    @rank = 1,
    @i = 1;

SELECT
    @prev := @curr,
    @rank := IF(
        @prev = @curr,
        @rank,
        @rank + @i
    ) AS rank,
    IF(
        @prev != SUM(wp_grank.points),
        @i := 1,
        @i := @i + 1
    ) AS counter,
    wp_grank.ID,
    wp_grank.competitor_ID ,
    wp_grank.tournament_ID ,
    wp_grank.academy_ID ,
    wp_grank.division_ID,
    wp_competitor.first_name,
    wp_competitor.last_name,
    wp_competitor.global_ID,
    wp_divisions.gender,
    IF(
        wp_divisions.age_level IN ('Tiny Kids','Kids','Pre Teen','Teen'),
        CONCAT('(',wp_divisions.gender,')'),
        ''
    ) as filterGender,
    wp_tournaments.`name` as tournament_name,
    wp_divisions.name as dname,
    CONCAT_WS(
        ' >> ',
        wp_divisions.division_type,
        wp_divisions.experience_level,
        wp_divisions.age_level,
        wp_divisions.weight_class,
        wp_divisions.gender
    ) as division,
    wp_academies.`name` as academy,
    @curr := SUM(wp_grank.points) as `totalPoints`
FROM
    `wp_grank`
    LEFT JOIN wp_competitor ON wp_grank.competitor_ID = wp_competitor.ID
    LEFT JOIN wp_tournaments ON wp_grank.tournament_ID = wp_tournaments.ID
    LEFT JOIN wp_academies ON wp_grank.academy_ID = wp_academies.ID
    LEFT JOIN wp_divisions ON wp_grank.division_ID = wp_divisions.ID
WHERE
    wp_divisions.ID IN (2)
    AND YEAR(wp_tournaments.tournament_date)=2015
GROUP BY wp_competitor.ID
ORDER BY
    `totalPoints` DESC,
    wp_competitor.`last_name` ASC;
```

**Note:**

- For the ranking with `tied` record(s) you need, I used `session variable` to define if the rank will `increase` or `retain` based in the previous value.

Cheers

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ': = 1, @i: = @i + 1 ) AS counter, wp_grank.ID, wp_grank.comp' at line 10

Comment: do we need to initialize value at beginning because all giving null.

Comment: yeah can, all the `@variables` to `0` except `@curr`, because it will come  from your `totalPoints` column

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108456/discussion-between-sismaster-and-avidos).

Comment: for some reason, I have limited access and cannot access SO chat, I updated the script. apologies mate

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

define a variable:

SET @row_number = 0;

Then wrap the query you have in:

```
select @row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS rank, [all the other columns here]
from ( [your nasty query here ] ) as myNastyNastyQuery;
```

Just make sure your ordering is done inside the nasty query.  LOL

Comment: above solution giving me ranks in serial order like 1 2 3 but if a points same for two user its should be 1,2,2

Comment: Unfortunately, MySQL does not have a true rank or dense_rank function.  LOL - Avidos scooped me!